# Error 404 page not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

old url

```
http://www.mywebsite.in/index.php/view-college?college_name=Suvidya+Institute+of+Technology%20(engineering)
```

new url

```
http://mywebsite.in/college/Suvidya%20Institute%20of%20Technology%20(engineering)
```

.htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Redirect 301 view-college.php?college_name=Suvidya+Institute+of+Technology%20(engineering)  http://mywebsite.in

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.in
```

I want to redirect my old url to my home page because I have move my core php project into codeigniter. In this htaccess file show me the 404 error page not found. May be my htaccess file is not correct. So, How can I fix this problem ?please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the above answer.From my research now, In Redirect we cannot use query string, So we need to use RewriteEngine

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} college_name=Suvidya\+Institute\+of\+Technology%20\(engineering\)
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.in? [R=302,L]
```

if RewriteEngine On is already written in your .htaccess file dont write that again only write the below two lines

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} college_name=Suvidya\+Institute\+of\+Technology%20\(engineering\)
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.in? [R=302,L]
```

I have executed the above code and it is working fine